# Named routes with arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having some difficulty with named routes.

I am trying to get some Firebase data to show on the screen after an `onPress` saves.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

DocumentSnapshot document;
final thisContact = Contact.fromSnapshot(document);

...

routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{ 
'/second': (BuildContext context) => ViewContact(contact: thisContact)
```

.

```
Contact.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
  : name = snapshot.data()['Name'],
    phoneNumber = snapshot.data()['PhoneNumber'],
    location = snapshot.data()['Location'],
    rating = snapshot.data()['Rating'],
    instagram = snapshot.data()['Instagram'],
    birthday = snapshot.data()['Birthday'],
    notes = snapshot.data()['Notes'];
```

The page with the save

```
onPressed: () async {
              final uid =
                  await TheProvider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();

              widget.contact.name = oneController.text;
              widget.contact.phoneNumber = int.tryParse(twoController.text);
              widget.contact.location = threeController.text;
              widget.contact.rating = int.tryParse(fourController.text);
              widget.contact.instagram = fiveController.text;
              widget.contact.birthday = int.tryParse(sixController.text);
              widget.contact.notes = sevenController.text;

              await db
                  .collection("userData")
                  .doc(uid)
                  .collection("Contacts")
                  .add(widget.contact.toJson());

              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/second");
            })
      ],
```

This causes the following error:

`The method 'data' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: data()`

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: You can share the code related "data".

Comment: @Akif Just added

Comment: document is null. You are not updating it before passing to Contact.fromSnapshot()

Comment: @Lee3 right, but it does work if I access the page afterwards through a `MaterialPageRoute`

Comment: Share the code from the page where you set the document value. I think your constructor may be incorrect.

Comment: @Lee3 Okay - added

Comment: [Navigation](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/navigate-without-build-context-in-flutter-using-a-navigation-service/). Check this awesome way of navigation.

Comment: @Lee3 could it be that I'm passing no arguments in the route on the `onPress` ?

Comment: @ashf that is indeed the problem. If you need an example of how to do so, I will provide one in an answer.

Comment: Actually, check this out https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data#alternatively-pass-the-arguments-using-routesettings. Jump to the routeSettings section as you are using named routes.

Comment: @Lee3 thank you for the link - I'm still a little bit confused. If I'm wanting to show firebase data,  does that `routeSettings` method work? I see nothing about `documents` etc. 

Would it not be easier to add some arguments to `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/second");` ?

Comment: Yes. You can pass the contact as an argument to `ViewContact` via `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed()` that will be available via the RouteSettings. I will write an answer demonstrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the parameter from the `ViewContact` constructor as we will be using route arguments.

```
routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{ 
  '/second': (BuildContext context) => ViewContact()
```

Pass the `Contact` as an argument to `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed()`.

```
onPressed: () async {
              ...
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/second", arguments: Contact.fromSnapshot(document));
        })
  ],
```

In the `build` method of `ViewContact`, or `initState` if it is a `StatefulWidget`:

```
  Contact contact = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

Comment: Thanks so far Lee you have been very helpful. I have just implemented that and now I'm getting `Too many positional arguments: 2 expected, but 3 found` for the `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed`. Also the `ViewContact` constructor is saying `The parameter 'contact' is required` - of course that can be ignored if it's working.

Comment: Sorry, I left of the arguments parameter name. Answer is updated.

Comment: Also, remove the `contact` field from the `ViewContact` class, as well as the `contact` named parameter from the `ViewContact` constructor in the `ViewContact` class.

Comment: Okay I've removed `final Contact contact;` and `ViewContact({Key key, @required this.contact}) : super(key: key);` from `ViewContact` class. When I click to view a contact it says `The getter 'location' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: location` even though location isn't null. It also won't direct to the `ViewContact` page on the `onPress`. Do you know what's causing this?

Comment: I can't be positive, but this appears to be occurring at this line: `widget.contact.location = threeController.text;`. Are you sure the `contact` field is initialized?

Comment: Yeah I just resolved that - had to change `MaterialPageRoute` (routes to `ViewContact`) on the home page to the same as on the `onPress` page. Re the save not routing - I'm now getting the original error of `NoSuchMethodError: The method 'data' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: data()`

Comment: Try passing `widget.contact` as the route argument.

Comment: Thank you so so much. Honestly - I really do appreciate the help Lee.